# How to insert one thymeleaf fragment to another?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf, fragment

Now I'm working with `html` on my `spring-app`, and decided to use `th:fragments` and `th:layouts`, because I'm tiered to cope/paste one code in each `.html` I'm creating. And its works accept on little thing - I don't know how to put `th:replace` into `th:insert`.

**index.html**

```
<head th:insert="fragments/utils.html :: headFragment">
        <title th:replace="fragments/utils.html :: headTitleFragment">HOME</title>
</head>
```

**mainTemplate.html**

```
<head th:fragment="headFragment">
        
        //some meta-tags

        <title th:fragment="headTitleFragment">HEAD</title>

        // some css-styles
    
</head>
```

So when I paste `headFragment`-fragment into my `index.html` its works as intended (I see it because all css-styles in place). But titles inside it wasn't replaced - it remains `HEAD` instead of `HOME`. So as I understand I can't put one `th:fragment` into another (in my case `headTitleFragment` into `headFragment`)?

If "no", how to fix it than? And if "yes" what should I do insted?